# Exception Error while compiling code with c++17

Tags: c++, exception, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename T> void mySort(Vector<T> *v, bool type) throw(const char *){
  v->sort(mode);
}
```

I GET THE FOLLOWING ERROR when I compile the above with C++17 compiler (gcc 11.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).

```
error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
   35 | template<typename T> void mySort(Vector<T> *v,bool type) throw(const char *){
      |                                                         ^~~~~
```

The compilation error disappears if I remove `throw(const char *)` from the code.
Is it a correct fix?

Comment: Yes, dynamic exception specification has been removed in C++17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec

Comment: They were deprecated already in C++11.

Comment: Off-topic: throwing anything not derived from `std::exception` is usually a bad idea.